# How to update User password in django

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-views, user-input

I'm having trouble when i try to update user password in django.

```
def password(request):
 if request.method=="POST":
    password =request.user.password
    username=request.user.username
    c_password=request.POST["current_password"]
    new_password=request.POST["new_password"]
    r_new_password=request.POST["retype_new_password"]
    if password==c_password:
        if new_password==r_new_password:
            user =User.objects.get(username=username)
            user.set_password(new_password)
            user.save()
            messages.info(request,"Successfully saved")
        else:
            messages.info(request,"PASSWORD DOES NOT MATCH")
    else:
        messages.info(request,"PASSWORD INCORRECT")
    
 return render(request,"security.html")
```

When i fill the current password, it is giving me error *password incorrect*. But, when i fill *pbkdf2_sha256$320000$Cb4s4nwqKwirdgo50ZdjLH$aeuSP3X+dSZXsv0XJB0XxkpwfsmU+PedMX9Jl50Zark=*
, my password becomes correct and user password is updateable. My problem is I would like to fill in current password field as normal current password without getting the error.

Comment: Use `authenticate`, do *not* check the `user.password`.

Comment: like how. can you explain a little bit

Comment: You should also consider using Django's built-in [`PasswordChangeView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordChangeView) insead of rolling your own implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [**`authenticate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) to validate the password: this will retrieve the hashing algorithm and the salt, and check if the hashes match, so you can work with:

```
def password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        c_password = request.POST['current_password']
        new_password = request.POST['new_password']
        r_new_password = request.POST['retype_new_password']
        user = authenticate(username=request.user.username, password=c_password)
        if user is not None:
            if new_password == r_new_password:
                user.set_password(new_password)
                user.save()
                messages.info(request, 'Successfully saved')
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'PASSWORDS DOE NOT MATCH')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'PASSWORD INCORRECT')
    return render(request, 'security.html')
```

There is however a [**`PasswordChangeView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordChangeView) to change the password: this already implements the logic and uses a form. You can inject a different template, for example with:

```
path(
    'password/change/',
    PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='security.html'),
    name='password_change'
)
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: It is better to use a [**`Form`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)
> than to perform manual validation and cleaning of the data. A `Form` will not
> only simplify *rendering* a form in HTML, but it also makes it more convenient
> to *validate* the input, and *clean* the data to a more convenient type.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords) Django does not store raw (plain text) passwords on the user model

use `authenticate` function instead of using `if password==c_password:`.

```py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
def password(request):
 if request.method=="POST":
    password =request.user.password
    username=request.user.username
    c_password=request.POST["current_password"]
    new_password=request.POST["new_password"]
    r_new_password=request.POST["retype_new_password"]
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=c_password)
    if user is not None:
        if new_password==r_new_password:
            user =User.objects.get(username=username)
            user.set_password(new_password)
            user.save()
            messages.info(request,"Successfully saved")
        else:
            messages.info(request,"PASSWORD DOES NOT MATCH")
    else:
        messages.info(request,"PASSWORD INCORRECT")
    
 return render(request,"security.html")
```